# Rospy getNumSubscribers()

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rospy do you have a `getNumSubscribers()` function for the Publisher?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416125/rospy-getnumsubscribers()/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2023-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, but it's [get_num_connections()](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1